# Question about local action of a group action

Tags: group-theory, algebraic-geometry, group-actions, algebraic-groups

In Milne's book "[Algebraic Groups: the theory of group schemes of finite type over a field. Cambridge](https://ebooks.cambridge.org/ref/id/CBO9781316711736?)", Chapter 8, proposition 8.9:

> X is also reduced
> [image]

In second paragraph of the proof, why we can get
$$\mathcal{I}\mathcal{O}_p \subset \mathfrak{m}^n_p$$

In the Corollary 8.10 which without assumption of $G$ is reduced:
[image]

Apply the proof to the faithful action $G/Z \times G \to G$ by conjugation, where $Z$ is centre, we get that $$G_{red} \subset G^H \subset G$$
where $H$ algebraic subgroups of $G/Z$.

We can also identity $G^H = C_G(H^{\prime})$, where $H^{\prime}$ algebraic subgroup of $G$ correspondence to $H$.

How can I get $H = {e}$ or $G^H = G$ or $H^{\prime} \subset Z$?

Appreciated for any help!

Comment: Please don't rely on pictures of text.

Comment: Relying on so much pictured text is strongly discouraged. [See here for many good reasons why you should not do it](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/34123/742).

Answer (score 1):

Assume $X$ is reduced in 8.9. Replace the proof of 8.10 with: Certainly, the kernels contain $Z(G)$.  As in the proof of 8.9, there exists an algebraic subgroup $H$ of $G$ such that $H$ is the kernel of $\rho_{n}\colon G\rightarrow\textrm{GL}_{\mathcal{O}_{e}/\mathfrak{m}_{e}^{n+1}}$
for all sufficiently large $n$. Moreover, $G^H$ (which equals $C_G(H)$) contains an open neighbourhood $U$ of $e$.
Now $C_G(H)$ contains $U\cdot U$, which equals $G$ (Exercise 1-2), and so $C_G(H)=G$. Therefore, $H\subset Z(G)$.

Comment: Thanks for your help. How about the first question? Why we have $\mathcal{I}\mathcal{O}_p \subset \mathfrak{m}^n_p$?